# Brute force dictionary attack example

Tags: security, wireshark, brute-force

This is an example of dictionary brute force attack however i do not understand the principle behind it. yes i do know that dictionary brute force is when an attacker tries combinations of passwords from a dictionary file. However, how is that explicitly shown in the capture below
[image]
If you feel that it would be more helpful to see the packets before this then please let me know.

ps. i apologise if the tags are incorrect

EDIT: the attacker is 192.168.56.1 and the victim is 192.168.56.101

EDIT: what i am trying to say is that this capture is from an assignment i was given. One of the questions in this assignment was:

- How did the attacker exploit this vulnerability to gain access ?

it is my belief that the vulnerability was that port 22 was left open (can be seen in other packets apart from this screenshot). A group of my friends suspect that the attacker used brute force to exploit this vulnerability and gain access.

My question is, is this true? can you tell that from this screenshot or would you need to see other packets? Can this screenshot be used as evidence that the attacker possibly used brute force to gain access?

Comment: If you are simulating a bruteforce to a SSH server or website over HTTPS, using a raw packet-capture might not be much helpful, because the all of the data are encrypted. So when you are not capturing a plain old HTTP or any other unencrypted traffic like ftp or telnet, there is no distinct way to know that by packet capture.

Comment: However, doesnt the fact that the session disconnects several times indicate that thats due to an incorrect password due to brute force

Comment: You're right. Something fishy like bruteforcing or DoS is going on, because you clearly see a lot of "SSH Server Banner" and "Key Exchange Inits". What I'm implying is that, over an encrypted channel you can't see the exact data being transmitted, so often times you just can't be exactly sure what type of attack is going on.

Comment: Agree with previous comments, but there's no actual question in the question. @JMoss can you fix your question to reflect this? You may want to look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it clearer.

Comment: @RossJacobs i apologies if the question seems a bit confusing im a bit new to stack and just started learning SSH and protocols. I edited the question to try and make it clearer. hope this helps.

Comment: @knoop so how would you answer the question:
- How did the attack exploit this vulnerability to gain access

Comment: Using only this encrypted capture, you don't know whether its a DoS or a bruteforce, because both look the same at the encrypted packet level. Now that your updated question is clear, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your assignment is a simple type of packet inspection then,

> The attacker gained access by bruteforcing the SSH service and the vulnerability is due to the use of weak password and the fact that it permitted password-based authentication.

1. By examining the screenshot of packet capture, we see a number of SSH authentication requests being made.
2. So, the attack must be carrying out either DoS or bruteforce.
3. The question explicitly states that the attacker has gained access.
4. Therefore, we know the attack is SSH-bruteforcing.

Update
Packettotal showed that the attacker was carrying out

1. Port Scanning (Indicator: use of ICMP echos)

[image: PortScan]

2. Smuggling Data from Web server

[image: smug]
[image: resp]

3. SSH Bruteforcing

[Link to the report](https://www.packettotal.com/app/analysis?id=3109189ffde07581785515a21c9cc9dc&name=ssh)

Update 2:
Manual packet analysis gave these results:

1. Attacker first used aggressive ARP scan to scan the hosts.
2. Started port scan on the victim.
3. Then found a SSH server and a web server running on the victim machine.
4. Tried bruteforcing SSH but failed
5. Sent a GET request to victim webserver and luckily it returned
   private SSH key
6. Has complete access to the victim

[image]

Comment: Now you know what is going on behind those packets, you can manually verify the information with wireshark.

Comment: Additionally, wireshark shows that there is active ARP scanning, which is used to discover the hosts in the newtork. After further digging in I found exactly how the attacker got access.

Comment: Sounds interesting. i also noticed the ARP scanning my only problem was i couldn't explain the brute forcing and how he got access to the config, public and private keys files